# Working on series $A(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-n}cos(nx)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to determine whether the two series as follows converge and then evaluate their sums:
$$A(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-n}cos(nx)$$
$$B(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-n}sin(nx)$$
I am thinking of using Dirichlet' theorem to prove that they converge:

a)The partial sums $A_{n}$ form a bounded sequence.

b) $b_{0} \geq b_{1} \geq b_{2} \geq...$

c) $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}b_{n} = 0;$

Then $\sum b_{n}a_{n}$ converges.

I think I can prove convergence but I cannot find a way to evaluate its sums.
Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: The convergence can be obtained using the comparison criterion. (The absolute value of cos(nx) or sin(nx) is bounded by 1 and $\sum_n 2^{-n}$ is a geometric series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using $e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$, we get
$$A(x)+iB(x) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(nx)+i\sin(nx)}{2^n} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{e^{ix}}{2}\right)^n = \frac{2}{2-e^{ix}}. \tag 1$$
But
$$\frac{2}{2-e^{ix}} = \frac{4-2\cos(x)}{5-4\cos(x)}+i \frac{2\sin(x)}{5-4\cos(x)}. \tag 2$$
Therefore,
$$A(x) = \frac{4-2\cos(x)}{5-4\cos(x)},\tag 3$$
and
$$B(x) = \frac{2\sin(x)}{5-4\cos(x)}.\tag 4$$

Comment: Hello, could you please give me another hint to evaluate that sum?

Comment: if I expand the term $e^{ix}$ and then multiple by a conjugate them, after cleaning up using algebra, I have the real part as $\frac{4-2cosx}{5-4cosx}$ and the imaginary part as $\frac{2sinx}{5-4cosx}$ which perfectly correspond to A(x) and B(x) on the left. Am I doing alright here? Thanks so much!

Comment: @Hugh Check the updated answer!

Comment: yay! I got it. Thanks so much, Math Lover